# Binance API, Error Code: -1102, Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed

Tags: linux, perl, curl, bitcoin

I am trying to get my account info from Binance.com with the following Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256_hex);
use Time::HiRes qw(time);

my $api_key = "X";
my $api_secret = "X";

my $data = "recvWindow=2000&timestamp=" . int(time() * 1000);
my $signature = uc(hmac_sha256_hex($data, $api_secret));

print `curl -s -m 3 -H 'X-MBX-APIKEY: $api_key' -d '$data&signature=$signature' -X GET 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account'` . "\n";
```

That code looks correct and should work, but I get the following error:

```
{"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}
```

Ofcourse, the timestamp parameter is sent and not empty or null, nor malformed.

If I print the output to console, it shows the following:

```
curl -s -m 3 -H 'X-MBX-APIKEY: X' -d 'recvWindow=2000&timestamp=1516082731909&signature=X' -X GET 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account'
```

Can someone help please?
Thank you.

References:

1. [Binance API official documentation / SIGNED Endpoint Examples](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-apiv1order)
2. [Account information](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#account-information-user_data)

Note: I replaced API Key/Secret and Signature with 'X'

Comment: According to reference link 1, it is correct.

Comment: Just tried, didn't work. Still the same error.

Comment: try using gettimeofday instead of time

Comment: Just tried, same output, same result.

Comment: Thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For `GET` endpoints, parameters must be sent as a `query string`.

Basically, the point of using `GET` is to allow the response to be cached, and having to deal with a request body would make that needlessly complicated. Therefore, the body of `GET` requests [should always be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/589924), so `-d` never makes sense for a `GET` request.

You can properly form the URL as follows:

```
use URI qw( );

my $url = URI->new('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account');
$url->query_form(
   recvWindow => 2000
   timestamp  => int(time() * 1000),
   signature  => uc(hmac_sha256_hex($data, $api_secret)),
);
```

You didn't just build the parameters incorrectly. You also had code injection bugs. You can properly form the shell command as follows:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote(
   'curl',
   '-s',
   '-m' => 3,
   '-H' => 'X-MBX-APIKEY: $api_key',
   '-X' => 'GET',
   $url,
);
```

Comment: Correct. Missed that (https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#general-api-information). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will re-do everything once the project is finished.